# managing multirow

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow

Hi I don't understand how to use multirow. I would like to do something like this"

[image]

I manage to do this:

[image]

Here is the code I used, I cant do any more.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcolumntype{d}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1\linewidth}}
\newcolumntype{e}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1\linewidth}}


\begin{document}

\noindent%
\begin{tabular}{|c|e{.28}|d{.15}|d{.15}|d{.11}|d{.11}|}
\hline
Lp. & Kryterium klasyfikacji & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Rodzaj (klasa) modelu} \\\hline

1 & Struktura modelu \newline i przedmiot modelowania & modele pojedyńczych procesów & modele komponentów & modele integralne & modele globalne\\\hline

2 & Stosowane metody badawcze & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{modele genetyczne} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{modele statystyczne}\\\hline

3 & Dostępność informacji \newline o badanym obiekcie & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{modele białej skrzynki} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{modele zarnej skrzynki}\\\hline

4 & Rola czynnika czasu & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{modele statyczne} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{modele dynamiczne}\\\hline

5 & Wartości poznawcze modelu & modele \newline przyczynowo- \newline -opisowe & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{modele symptomatyczne \newline (konceptualne)} & modele tendencji\\\hline

\multirow{3}{*}{6} & \multirow{3}{*}{Własności funkcji przekształcającej (operatora)} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{modele nielinowe} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{modele liniowe} \\ \cline{3-6} 


\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Also I would like to wrap text "modele symptomatyczne(konceptualne)" in a way that "(konceptualne)" would be under the "modele symptomatyczne".

And in second row for some reason "modele integralne" is snapping to the left

Answer (score 1):

Use a `d` specification in the cell: `\multicolumn{2}{d{.27}|}{modele symptomatyczne (konceptualne)}`.

Also the `\multirow` in a fixed width column should use `{=}` instead of `{*}` to use the column width.

**EDIT:** I finished the whole table (sorry, I missed some accents). Some more remarks.
:

1. It would be better to make the two last columns a bit wider so that `modele deterministyczne` would fit on one line.
2. The `\multicol`s have a `d{...}` specification with the sum of both column width (actually it should be a little bit more to include the intercolumn space), instead of `c`, otherwise there will be no line breaks.
3. I have changed the `\multirow` to `{4}` instead of `{3}` because the actual number of lines is 4.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcolumntype{d}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1\linewidth}}
\newcolumntype{e}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1\linewidth}}


\begin{document}

\noindent%
\begin{tabular}{|c|e{.28}|d{.15}|d{.15}|d{.11}|d{.11}|}
\hline
Lp. & Kryterium klasyfikacji & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Rodzaj (klasa) modelu} \\\hline

1 & Struktura modelu \newline i przedmiot modelowania & modele pojedyńczych procesów & modele komponentów & modele integralne & modele globalne\\\hline

2 & Stosowane metody badawcze & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{modele genetyczne} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{modele statystyczne}\\\hline

3 & Dostępność informacji \newline o badanym obiekcie & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{modele białej skrzynki} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{modele zarnej skrzynki}\\\hline

4 & Rola czynnika czasu & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{modele statyczne} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{modele dynamiczne}\\\hline

5 & Wartości poznawcze modelu & modele \newline przyczynowo- \newline -opisowe & \multicolumn{2}{d{.27}|}{modele symptomatyczne (konceptualne)} & modele tendencji\\\hline

\multirow{4}{*}{6} & \multirow{4}{=}{Własności funkcji przekształcającej (operatora)} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{modele liniowe} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{modele nielinowe} \\ \cline{3-6} 

  & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{modele stacjonarne} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{modele niestacjonarne}  \\ \cline{3-6} 

  & & \multicolumn{2}{d{.3}|}{modele o parametrach skupionych} & \multicolumn{2}{d{.22}|}{modele o parametrach rozłozonych}   \\ \hline

7 & Jednoznacznosc uzyskiwanych wynikow & \multicolumn{2}{d{.3}|}{modele deterministyczne} & \multicolumn{2}{d{.22}|}{modele probabilistyczne} \\ \hline
 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `tabularray` package is simple to design your table. From your MWE is no entirely clear why you use `multirow`. Observed provided image, which seems was not produced by your code, an exception for use of the multirow may be in the last three (or tow?) table rows. It is not needed for your table:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}
\noindent%
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec={l X[2.5,l,m] X[1,c,m]X[1.2,c,m] X[0.9,c,m] X[0.9,c,m]},
             colsep=4pt,
             row{1}={font=\bfseries},
             }
Lp. & \SetCell[c=1]{l} Kryterium klasyfikacji 
        & \SetCell[c=4]{c} Rodzaj (klasa) modelu    &   &   &           \\
%
1   & Struktura modelu i przedmiot modelowania 
        & Modele pojedyńczych procesów 
            & Modele komponentów 
                & Modele integralne 
                    & Modele globalne                                   \\
2   & Stosowane metody badawcze 
        & \SetCell[c=2]{c} modele genetyczne    &
            & \SetCell[c=2]{c} modele statystyczne  &                   \\
3   & Dostępność informacji o badanym obiekcie 
        & \SetCell[c=2]{c} modele białej skrzynki   & 
            & \SetCell[c=2]{c} modele zarnej skrzynki   &               \\
4   & Rola czynnika czasu 
        & \SetCell[c=2]{c} modele statyczne     & 
            & \SetCell[c=2]{c} modele dynamiczne    &                   \\
5   & Wartości poznawcze modelu 
        & modele przyczynowo opisowe 
            & modele symptomatyczne (konceptualne) & 
                & modele tendencji                                      \\
 \SetCell[r=2]{c} 6     % <--- this part of your MWE is unclear
    &  Własności funkcji przekształcającej (operatora) 
        & \SetCell[c=2]{c} modele nielinowe &  
            & \SetCell[c=2]{c} modele liniowe   &                       \\
   &   &   &   &   &                                                   \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```